# Сравнение производительности веб-серверов для отдачи статики

Tags: nginx, производительность, iis

Есть некоторый проект, основная часть крутится на последнем IIS - но помимо основной обвязки asp.net необходимо ещё раздавать статику (картинки до ~ 4 мб весом и превьюшки на ~ 30 кб), её на несколько гигабайт -- вполне можно выделить отдельный сервер.

И встал у меня вопрос: стоит ли сделать картиночный сервер так же на IIS, либо поставить отдельную машину на базе nginx? (Заливать в облака -- модный вариант, но не мой) 
Как ни сравнивали -- по всем статьям нет никакой разницы, на какой технологии делать -- есть и сервера и специалисты.
Единственный пункт, который как мне кажется влияет на выбор -- это производительность. Будет ли IIS заметно быстрее/медленнее, чем nginx?

Пробовал искать в сети, но информации никакой нет, сплошной маркетинг.

По-хорошему, надо бы поднять пару тестовых виртуалок и сравнить, но может быть кто-либо уже занимался подобными сравнениями или видел чужие исследования? ;)

PS Понимая, что вопрос несколько на грани ("...порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях") постарался максимально сузить область: только производительность, только на статическом контенте.

Comment: На самом деле Ваш вопрос сводится к windows/linux(или bsd). Ответьте на этот вопрос и Вы автоматом ответите на свой.

Comment: @KoVadim Да я вроде в достаточной мере умею "готовить кошек", чтобы и то и другое настроить для нужд "кровавого энтерпрайза". Но в целом я мысль уловил. Выбор win/lin -- это ещё тот холивар.

Comment: По мне, лучше не плодить сущности и раз всё уже работает на IIS, то и картинки им же отдавать.